# AlertDialog gets reshown on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-databinding, android-architecture-components

[Code for question on Github](https://github.com/Wicked0ne/ABug)
I have a app which is using fragments + viewmodels. In one fragment I need to present a list of options to the user when they hit a button. I'm doing this using an AlertDialog builder and it works to solve that problem. But if I open the application, hit the button to show the alertdialog, dismiss the dialog, and then rotate the phone to trigger a teardown/buildup the alertdialog get's reshown.

I'm using Android's databinding to bind ui stuff to the ViewModel(not sure if it matters). So the basic flow is:

- App starts
- Fragment subscribes to 1 observable in the ViewModel
- User clicks button
- Due to databinding the click is handled in the ViewModel by the method buttonClicked()
- Inside vm.buttonClicked() function I get data and update the observable the fragment is observing
- Fragment see's new data in observable
- Fragment creates AlertDialog in code and shows dialog to user
- User either makes a selection or dismisses the dialog
- User rotates phone, causes lifecycle change
- When the ui get's rebuilt, it shows the AlertDialog again

I have created a simple demo on [github](https://github.com/Wicked0ne/ABug).

If you clone that repo then start the app but DONT hit the button, orientation changes go as expected. If you click the button and dismiss the dialog then rotate the phone, you'll see that the AlertDialog get's reshown.

Comment: Use a DialogFragment.

Comment: I tried that as well, I had the same issue. I was overriding the onCreateDialog() method to create and return the AlertDialog

Answer (score 1):

ViewModel's lifecycle is different than of the fragment. When the orientation changes the Fragment gets recreated but the ViewModel stays.

Now what's happening is, when you update the value of the MutableLiveData it broadcasts an update to the Observer; when the Fragment is recreated on rotation change, it subscribes to the LiveData all over again and since there is an update on the value, the MutableLiveData broadcasts the update to the newly subscribed observer.

So you should, for example, save your fragment state in `onSaveInstanceState`, use the savedInstanceState to get the last update to the MutableLiveData value and check if a change had happened in the observer before showing the dialog.

Or you can move the dialog logic to the on click handler. Showing a dialog in an Observer is not a good approach in my opinion.

Comment: I'm still a noob, but I thought that LiveData did not "re broadcast" things. I.e A fragment observes a LiveData var from the VM. If the livedata changes when the fragment is observing, the frag reacts. But lets say the frag is not observing while the livedata in the VM changes. When the frag restarts and starts observing the livedata... it doesn't get sent the data that changed while it was not listening? Does it?

Comment: Think of it this way; if it has a value when someone starts observing, it will notify the observer of that value.

Comment: Hmm, I was under the impression that when you start to observe something(unless otherwise configured to do so) you only get future changes.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#work_livedata) to get a better understanding, and you are not a noob this is advanced stuff(:

Comment: No denying I need to get a better grasp on how this works. Thanks for the input and link, I do appreciate it!

Comment: It looks like you where right. I completely misunderstood LiveData. After some reading I came across this post that helped me out. It will do for now, thanks! https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with LiveData and events, [this](https://proandroiddev.com/singleliveevent-to-help-you-work-with-livedata-and-events-5ac519989c70) can help you to tackle some scenarios. In summary, you should work with ***SingleLiveEvents***